# Values of ICollection objects are being returned null when posting a form...MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a collection of objects as so:

```
   public ICollection<EmailViewModel> Emails { get; set; }
```

I populate a razor view inside a form with the objects and they display fine:

```
          <div>Emails:</div>
     @foreach (var item in Model.Emails)
     {
    <div class="margins">
        <span class="textRight">@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Type)</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => item.Address, new {@class = "name rmargin5"})
    </div>
     }
```

When I click submit and look inside my view model object being passed back, my Emails collection is null.

```
   public ActionResult CheckResults(MyViewModel myViewModel){

                   //  myViewModel.Emails is null
           }
```

It's not null when I send it to the form, but its null coming back. Does anyone know why?

Thank you...

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412765/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-to-nested-collection

Comment: Thanks for responding. But you cant index an ICollection object

Comment: Consider not posting back a ViewModel (but rather its constituents).  They're meant to provide a strongly-typed mechanism for presentation of data, not its modification.