# Model Bind to Variable Length List

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

How can a UI be built that allows the user to create options for a question? The view (Form.cshtml) should allow a variable amount of text inputs (two or more at anytime) to bind to variable amount of @Model.Options[i].OptionText. Is there Razor markup or tag helpers that can be used to accomplish this?
The reason that there is a class "Option" is that Entity Framework Core does not allow persistence of a collection of primitive types, including strings.

**Option.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Models
{
     public class Option
     {
         public int OptionId { get; set; }
         public string OptionText { get; set; }
         public int QuestionId { get; set; }
         public Question Question { get; set; }
     }
}
```

**Question.cs**

```
namespace MyProject.Models 
{
    public class Question
    {
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Option> Options { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CreateQuestionModel.cs**

```
public class CreateQuestionModel
{
    [Required]
    [UIHint("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UIHint("hidden")]
    public int FormId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Options> Options{ get; set; }
}
```

**Form.cshmtl**

```
@model CreateQuestionModel

<form asp-controller="Form" asp-action="Options" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Text">Question name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.Text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Options"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="???">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@Model.Options"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="???">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Options</button>
</form>
```

**FormController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Options([Bind("Text, Choices")] Question question)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        context.Add(question);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction("/");
    }

    return RedirectToAction("/");
}
```

Comment: https://www.wiliam.com.au/wiliam-blog/asp-net-mvc-5-view-model-collection-binding

Comment: Are there tag helpers available to accomplish this without needing the for loop in the view?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18412765/asp-net-mvc-model-binding-to-nested-collection

Comment: I see your second comment again suggests the loop approach paired with the "@Html" syntax, but I was hoping to gain more control of the markup using HTML and tag helpers. This would allow me to add custom attributes such as classes.

Comment: There is no HTML helper available to render input for the entire collection. Looping is the only way. You can write your own HTML helper for this if you want.

Comment: The tag helper should not be used to render an entire collection, because there is not currently existing collection. It should only render inputs that will bind to the View Model in the Controller. Hoping that there is a tag helper for this.

For example this plain HTML works too:
<input class="form-control" name="Choices[0].ChoiceText" type="text" value="" />

Is there any way to generate two or more of these without a loop? Like this?

<input class="form-control" asp-tag-helper-???="???" type="text" value="" />

Comment: No there are no such tag helpers. You might want to explore some other tools and libraries but nothing available from Microsoft or MVC.